# docker with bower, grunt

Tags: gruntjs, docker, bower

I'm trying to build a docker image with grunt and bower but i get the 
following exception

2015/01/19 23:21:55 The command [/bin/sh -c grunt] returned a non-zero code: 1

similar exception printed for bower too.
my Dockerfile is like.

what can be the problem ?

```
FROM    ubuntu:14.04

RUN     apt-get update
RUN     apt-get install -y node npm git git-core
RUN     ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node
COPY    . /app

WORKDIR /app

RUN     npm install -g bower 
RUN     npm install -g grunt-cli
RUN     npm install 
# RUN     bower install 
RUN     grunt 
RUN     grunt serve
EXPOSE  9000
```

BTW. i did not grasp all this docker thing. 
I enter the image with

```
docker run -t -i a87274a7f3b7  /bin/bash
```

and jast run

```
grunt
```

but nothing happens it just doest nothing and doesnot give any error.

edit 
this one seems working

```
FROM    ubuntu:14.04

RUN     apt-get update
RUN     apt-get install -y nodejs npm git git-core
RUN     ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node
COPY    . /app

WORKDIR /app

RUN     npm install -g bower 
RUN     npm install -g grunt-cli
RUN     npm install 
RUN     bower install --allow-root
RUN     grunt 
RUN     grunt serve
EXPOSE  9000
```

Comment: `apt-get install --yes node` installs `ax25-node`,  a ham radio program also called node in /usr/sbin/node,  while `npm` installs node.js as a dependency.  Suggest omitting node and/or specifying nodejs instead.

Comment: I have run your commands by hand in a `docker run -it ubuntu:14.04` and can't duplicate the problem, possibly because I don't have the app you are trying to set up,  The apt-gets and npm installs work, even though ax25-node is installed as /usr/sbin/node as an unwanted side-effect.  running grunt or bower thereafter works as well but does nothing as there are no commands set up to run.

Comment: Hmm, removing ax25-node and symlinking /usr/bin/node-->/usr/bin/nodejs causes grunt to spit out some messages on startup instead of nothing.  /usr/local/bin/grunt is a script, beginning `#!/usr/bin/env node` so it will get tricked into running whichever node is in the PATH.  If thats the ham radio node, instead of nodejs, it wont work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Ubuntu repository node is not nodejs, it is a ham radio node program called ax25-node, that gets installed as /usr/sbin/node.  Grunt then gets confused, as it is merely a script with shebang `#!/usr/bin/env node` and will execute whatever equates to `node` on the `$PATH`.

To fix:

replace

```
RUN     apt-get install -y node npm git git-core
```

with

```
RUN     apt-get install -y nodejs npm git git-core
```

Comment: thanks i changed my Dockerfile. see my edit. i had other minor problems but things seems working basically